# Html Table - Select the option only once

Tags: html, select, html-table

i have table where i have a select box which displays options.
[image]

when i select a value in a row that must not be displayed in other rows.For example in the below image,in first row i have selected casual shoes in other rows casual shoes must not be displayed.[image]

Any Help with example or coding are welcome.Thanks!!

```
<td>
    <select name="proname[]" class="form-control proname">
        <option value="" selected="true" disabled="true">SelectProduct</option> @foreach($proname as $v)
        <option value="{{$v->itemname}}">{{$v->itemname}}</option> @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

In my controller:

```
public function putbillpage() {
    $proname = productmodel::select('itemname')->get();
    return view('putbillpage', compact('proname'));
}
```

Comment: This is pretty simple. Anyone here is willing to help you, but are you willing to help yourself? What have you tried yet? Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Are you using a JS framework? Can you post your HTML / JS code?

Comment: Put you code  to know what is the wrong

Comment: @Junaid I have been googling and found none matching. That is reason i am posting question here! As you said simple i am expecting answer from you.

Comment: @Nivas At least show us your HTML code.

Comment: @D.Simon No I am not using any JS Framework. I am working Laravel PHP Framework. My Html Code is

`<td><select name="proname[]" class="form-control proname">
<option value="" selected="true" disabled="true">SelectProduct</option>
@foreach($proname as $v)
  <option value="{{$v->itemname}}" >{{$v->itemname}}</option>          
@endforeach
  </select></td>`

In my controller:

`public function putbillpage()
    {
  
      $proname = productmodel::select('itemname')->get();
        return view('putbillpage', compact('proname'));
    }`

Comment: @ZAhmed code is in above comment

Comment: @Junaid its in above command